# Who manufactured this shower diverter valve?

Tags: shower, plumbing-fixture, old-house, us

I am replacing the diverter valve in a 1963 residential shower and wondering if anyone knows the make and model from the maker's marks on this hardware?

I see imprinted: `P-P`, `C.W.`, and `18`. The hardware appears to be cast iron and brass, with one nylon lock washer, and one rubber washer.

[image: diverter valve stamped P-P]

[image: diverter valve stamped C.W. and 18]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"P-P" is likely Price-Pfister. Since 2010, they have been known simply as [Pfister](https://www.pfisterfaucets.com/).

Comment: Totally forgot about my question. You're correct. I took it to a most awesome specialty plumbing shop who knew it right away and found a replacement.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it, @bishop